# Which definition is this article using of the verb "temper"?

Tags: word-meaning

Currently reading [**this article**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/brexit-news-latest-boris-johnson-102100996.html), the last paragraph says,

> Mr Grant said: “FRA & GER used to each work with the UK to create a balance v the other. Now they’ve only each other to get annoyed with. And other members are much warier of Franco-German dominance, **without UK to temper** FRA’s & GER’s influence.”

My dictionary gives the definitions,

> transitive verb
>
> 1
>   a :  to dilute, qualify, or soften (as something strong, harsh, or excessive) by the addition or influence of something else :  make temperate :  moderate, season
>
> b :  to make suitable for :  adapt to :  adjust, modify — usually used with to
>
> c archaic :  to mix (ingredients) in suitable proportions :  prepare by combining :  compound, blend
>
> 2
>   archaic
>   a :  to exercise control over :  govern, restrain
>
> b :  to cause to be well disposed :  mollify
>
> 3
>   :  to bring (a substance or material) to a suitable state (as of consistency or workability) by mixing in or adding a usually liquid ingredient: such as
>
> a (1) :  to mix (clay) with water and knead to a uniform texture (2) :  to add an aplastic material (as grog or sand) to (clay)
>
> b :  to mix oil with (colors) in making paint ready for use
>
> c :  to moisten (as sand for molding) to a proper consistency and stir thoroughly
>
> d :  to dampen or remove moisture from (grain) to secure the best grinding
>
> e :  to make (leather) uniformly moist and soft for further processing
>
> 4
>   a (1) :  to soften (hardened steel or cast iron) by reheating at a temperature well below that from which previous quenching for hardening was done (2) :  to harden and reheat (steel or cast iron) or to harden alone especially in oil — not used technically
>
> b :  to anneal or toughen (glass) by a process of gradually heating and cooling
>
> 5
>   :  to make stronger and more resilient through hardship :  toughen
>
> 6
>   a :  to put in tune with :  attune
>
> b :  to adjust the pitch of (a note, chord, instrument) to a temperament

Thank you in advance(m_m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in this

> ... And other members are much **warier** of Franco-German **dominance**, without UK to **temper** FRA’s & GER’s **influence**.

What this is saying is that with out UK's presence, other members of the EU are worried about France and German's strong dominance.

> If you are **wary** of something or someone, you are cautious because you do not know much about them and you believe they may be dangerous or cause problems (Collins).

The question is, why are they much warier now? What role did UK play before? UK helped keep the power balanced (e.g., in trade, politics).

"Temper" here means to reduce or lessen

> to make something less strong, extreme, etc. (Cambridge)

So it should be the first definition in your list.

> 1 a : to dilute, qualify, or soften (as something strong, harsh, or excessive) by the addition or influence of something else : make temperate : moderate, season